# How to use SignalR to re-direct after Session timeout?

Tags: signalr, session-state, session-timeout

I am using SignalR to redirect my app after session timeout:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var HubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        HubContext.Clients.All.clientListener(false);}
```

And my Hub class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void ServerListener(bool result)
    {
        Clients.Caller.ClientListener(result);
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
var myHub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.start()
     .done(function () {
         console.log("Connected");
})
.fail(function () {
    alert("Failed!");
})

myHub.client.clientListener = function (data) {
    if (data == false)
        window.location.href = "/Home/Index";//@Url.Action("Index","Home");
}
})();
```

The Problems that I face is:

1. When multiple users are connected all users are logged out at the same time, even if they logged in at different times.
2. Logout redirection occurs even if regular requests are made.

It would really help me, if someone could tell me how to do a "server push" without invoking the Session_End() as I want to use some other session state other than "In Proc".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Question #1:

Since you're using `HubContext.Clients.All.clientListener` all users connected to SignalR are indeed going to receive the message from the server - it doesn't matter when they logged in to your app.

You should use this guide to send a message from the server to a specific user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections .
Personally I like single-user groups idea https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#single-user-groups.

As for the additional question, as long as you can get the hub reference with `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>()` all you have to do is call a registered client side method to perform a server push (e.g. `Clients.Group(userid).clientListener(false)`). It's not something that has to be done exclusively on `Session_End()`.

Comment: How will the client know that the session has timed out to invoke a server function? @mauriciorcruz

Comment: @InnocentCriminal I thought you wanted to call a client method from the server right before the session has timed out. Just to clarify - are you trying to use SignalR exclusively to make the client aware of the session state?

Comment: No I'm Using signalR for real time chatting as well. Thanks @mauriciorcruz

Answer (score 1):

What I did is:

1. On Page_Load I update a hidden label with the Session.SessionId
2. Pass it via query string before starting hub on client:

```
    $.connection.hub.qs = { "sessionId": $("#lblSessionId").text() };
```

3. On the server side in the hub OnConnected/OnReconnected I call this method to store the correlation of sessionId->connectionId in dictionary:

```
private void AddConnectedClient()
{
    // read the [ASP.Net] sessionId we send from client in queryString
    string sessionId = Context.Request.QueryString["sessionId"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
        sessionIdToConnectionId.AddOrUpdate(sessionId, Context.ConnectionId, (k, v) => Context.ConnectionId);
}
```

4. Now in the Session_End I have this code (GetConnectionIdFromSessionId is a static method I added in hub to read from sessionIdToConnectionId dictionary shown in #3):

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // look for signalR connecitonId
    string connectionID = YourHub.GetConnectionIdFromSessionId(Session.SessionID);
    if (connectionID != null)
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHub>().Clients.Client(connectionID).onSessionExpired();
}
```